# Donut disappears when adding sprinkles

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am a teacher, new to Blender.  We are learning together using the Blender Guru donut, version 3.0.  In video 9, when adding sprinkle nodes, it looks like the donut is not there, but it still appears in the outliner.  I've no idea how to help her and I couldn't find this issue when searching. We had previously tried Alt + H.

Here is her screen shot.[image]

Comment: Try hitting Alt-H (unhide all) in case it's been hidden by mistake with the H key.

Comment: if John's solution doesn't work please show a screenshot of your whole interface

Comment: As @moonboots says a screenshot would be helpful. In Blender use the Window > Save Screenshot menu then edit your question above and add the image into it.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the distribute points on faces node, you can't see the original mesh. So to fix this, add the join geometry node, at the end of the node setup, and plug the original geometry into the join geometry, so that you can see both the particles and the original mesh. See attached photo.

[image]